# How does Java handle low level Socket Networking logic

Tags: java, sockets

Please can some one point me to source code where Java handles low level Socket Networking logic like C# does using **[[DllImport(WS2_32, SetLastError = true)]](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/net/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,3c80e1093b4b741c)**

I am trying to understand how Java handles low level networking logic like C# does using DLLImport.

Finding hard time to trace the implementation of SocketImpl or SocketImplFactory  logic in [java.net.Socket](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/net/Socket-source.html) source code. Even if I am able to trace it to [AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/net/AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java) implimentation of SocketImpl there seems to be no implementation for **connect0** to dig deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look for concrete child classes of [java.net.SocketImpl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketImpl.html) like [DualStackPlainSocketImpl](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/e4f2a8ab1709/src/windows/classes/java/net/DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java).

There are places where implementation calls to native functions:

```
connectResult = connect0(nativefd, address, port);
....
static native int connect0(int fd, InetAddress remote, int remotePort)
    throws IOException;
```

Native code is quite often platform specific and implemented by C++ or C.
One Windows example from [DualStackPlainSocketImpl.c](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/e4f2a8ab1709/src/windows/native/java/net/DualStackPlainSocketImpl.c) of OpenJDK/jdk8u:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_java_net_DualStackPlainSocketImpl_connect0
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jint fd, jobject iaObj, jint port) 
{
    SOCKETADDRESS sa;
    ...
    rv = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sa_len);
```

In the example `connnect()` call is probably the level what you are looking for: [WinSock2 API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) in Windows. From Linux sources you will find similar [connnect()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) system call.